# how to match two columns using one of the column as reference?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, multiple-columns

I have done some analysis and have found a particular pattern , and now I am trying to do some predictions. 
I have a data set that predicts the ratings for students with a given number of accidents in their childhood. 
My prediction matrix is looks some thing like this:

```
   A
   injuries      ratings  
         0            5
         1            4.89
         2            4.34
         3            3.99 
         4            3.89
         5            3.77
```

and my dataset looks like this:

```
B

siblings income injuries total_scoldings_from father
     3       12000   4             09
     4       34000   5             22
     1       23400   3             12
     3       24330   1              1
     0       12000   1             12
```

now i want to create a column name **predictions** that essentially matches the entries from `A` to `B` and returns

```
siblings income injuries total_scoldings_from_father predictions
     3       12000   4             09                    3.89
     4       34000   5             22                    3.77
     1       23400   3             12                    3.99
     3       24330   1             1                     4.89
     0       12000   1             12                    4.89
```

please help

Also suggest a title as mine lacks everything important for future references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) if all values for mapping are in DataFrame `A`:

```
B['predictions'] = B['injuries'].map(A.set_index('injuries')['ratings'])
print (B)
   siblings  income  injuries  total_scoldings_from_father  predictions
0         3   12000         4                            9         3.89
1         4   34000         5                           22         3.77
2         1   23400         3                           12         3.99
3         3   24330         1                            1         4.89
4         0   12000         1                           12         4.89
```

Another solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
C = pd.merge(B,A)
print (C)
   siblings  income  injuries  total_scoldings_from_father  ratings
0         3   12000         4                            9     3.89
1         4   34000         5                           22     3.77
2         1   23400         3                           12     3.99
3         3   24330         1                            1     4.89
4         0   12000         1                           12     4.89
```

Comment: will merge work if B has a lot more rows than A , as A is just a reference matrix ?  also is is my title appropriate ?

Comment: Yes, DataFrame A is used as reference and `merge` solution works, if A has only two columns. If there is multiple columns, use subset `C = pd.merge(B,A[['injuries','ratings']])`